# T-SQL: can I script a INSERT from a SELECT?

Tags: t-sql, select, insert

I have a set of records on my home computer that can be retrieved with this simple query:

```
SELECT * from mydb.dbo.topics where name like 'about%'
```

I would like to convert the result of the query above into a insert script that I can run in my office computer.

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If the number of columns is reasonable you should be able to `select 'insert into Office.Table ( Col1, Col2 ) values ( ' + Col1 + ', ' + Col2 + ' );' from mydb.dbo.topics where name like 'about%';`. You'll need to ensure that the column values are converted, as needed, to text and appropriately quoted. SSMS can output to text rather than a grid and you can cut'n'paste the result.

Comment: Cool, I didn't think of it. A bit more laborious than I would wish but far less than do everything by hand! Thank you for the heads up!